# Ruby on Rails how to include a form in an index view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been running my head into a wall for hours now and I can't make this work. I'm trying to add a bunch of check boxes to verify items on my index page. I found [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes?view=comments) old rails cast that does exactly what I want to do, but I've run into a problem. Anything enclosed inside my form is removed from the index page, like just gone poof. Here's the code from the index view.

```
  <% form_tag verify_products_path, :method => :put do %>
    <% @products_unverified.each do |products| %>
      <% if product.deleted != 'true' %>
        <tr data-link="<%= product_path(product) %>">
          <td><%= product.name %></td>
          <td><%= product.description %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Mark as Verified" %>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Here's the routes stuff

```
  resources :products do
    put :verify, :on => :collection
  end
```

and the controller just has a dummy method for now.

```
def verify

end
```

Any clue as to why the index view blanks out when the form is introduced? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `=` before `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag verify_products_path, :method => :put do %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. I even passed this by 3 other dev's before I posted this question we all missed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

put an = in front of form_tag
instead of

```
<% form_tag verify_products_path, :method => :put do %>
```

try

```
<%= form_tag verify_products_path, :method => :put do %>
```